# Subsetting data frame with list of times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, subset

I have a df with a time index structured as so:

```
                     Sensor  UnitNo
Time                               
2016-07-28 18:34:44    19.0     1.0
2016-07-28 19:27:39    19.0     1.0
2016-07-20 20:45:39    19.0     1.0
2016-07-20 23:05:29    19.0     1.0
2016-07-21 01:23:30    19.0     1.0
...
```

I want to subset this df with a Series with a time index and a boolean column:

```
    Time
2016-07-28    False
2016-07-21    False
2016-07-20     True
```

I want to subset the original df for the `True` dates in the Series:

```
                     Sensor  UnitNo
Time                               
2016-07-20 20:45:39    19.0     1.0
2016-07-20 23:05:29    19.0     1.0
```

**UPDATE**
Apologies, when I first asked this question I thought I could easily convert the Series into a list of times, but I have found that problematic for several reasons. So, I updated the question above to resemble the current state of my data. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try `str.contains`

```
List=['2016-07-28','2016-07-20']
List1=('|'.join(List))
df[df.index.to_series().str.contains(List1)]



                       Sensor  UnitNo
Time                               
2016-07-28 18:34:44      19       1
2016-07-28 19:27:39      19       1
2016-07-20 20:45:39      19       1
2016-07-20 23:05:29      19       1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [.loc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-label)

```
df.loc[['2016-07-28', '2016-07-20'],:]
```

UPDATE

Doesn't it work if you use that boolean `Series` directly as a boolean index to the `Dataframe`?

```
df.loc[bool_series, :]
```

Comment: No, I get the following error: `raise IndexingError('Unalignable boolean Series key provided')
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided`

Comment: The `bool_series` is a downsampled version of the df, so they do not have the same number of rows.

Comment: ...and if I do this: `df_tmp.loc[bool_series.index, :]` it gives me an error that none of the dates in the `df` are in the `bool_series.index`. I *think* this has something to do with pandas thinking I am passing a `datetime` object rather than a `date` object, i.e., it is looking for an exact match of time instant rather than a period of time (i.e., one day).

Comment: Right. I didn't pay attention to the downsampling. (I assumed you had simplified it when copying it in the question.) You could add a column to the original dataframe with the date corresponding to the index datetime, and use this column to match the boolean table, but it won't be as straightforward as boolean indexing, you may have to use a python loop. I don't see a pure Pandas way, although it may exist, I'm no Pandas specialist.